# How to use only one library (are multiple same ones)

Tags: android, module, duplicates, external

Situation is that I in my project use library A. I also import external library which also has itself a library A. So as you can assume, when I try to compile, I receive Multiple DEX files define error which means that there are duplications.

However, If I remove my library from the project, I cannot use its provided methods. And I cannot find how can I remove that library from the module.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Eclipse? Android Studio+Gradle? etc

Comment: What is your problem, you want to know how to remove the Lib or how to use same lib multiple time?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to exclude it like this:

```
compile('library:1.0.0') {
exclude group: 'something', module: 'something'
}
```

So do this on the external library for all the things you're using that's causing a problem.

From here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency/2119/2

Answer (score 0):

define multiDexEnable True in your build.gradle(app)

```
defaultConfig {

    multiDexEnabled true
 }
```

and also define in dependency in same build.gradle(app)

```
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your suggestions. 
I didn't want to do as Michael suggested because I believe it is kind of useless (having multiple libraries with same purpose) (already knew this trick). 
I have tried Ядм Жцмдшдт answer, but couldn't succeed in compiling code completely. I have received various errors.

In the end I have solved my own issue. What I did:

Remove library from my main app libs folder. Remove dependancies if any in Android Studio (File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies (On module app) -> remove if any regarding your library. 
Clean project in Android Studio (Build -> Clean Project).
Go to the module where my library A is. Go to that module build.gradle file and add following line in the dependencies cluster

> compile files('libs/libraryA.jar')

Sync code and enjoy results.

TLDR
I didn't have libraryA compiled in my external module but it threw me duplication error, that's where I was confused. By removing it from my main project and adding it to my module's compilations list solved the problem.