# imlement 3rd party libraries .jar files into android module

Tags: android, android-module

Hello guys i wanna implement retrofit libraries into my module like this :

```
implementation files('libs/timber-3.1.0')
implementation files('libs/retrofit-2.3.0')
implementation files('libs/logging-interceptor-3.8.0')
implementation files('libs/gson-2.7')
implementation files('libs/converter-gson-2.3.0')
```

but if any user will use this module will implement the same libraries into his app/gradle file will face issues with multidex, so any help to be able to use those libs into my module ??

Comment: Refer this answer, similar solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529967/how-to-use-only-one-library-are-multiple-same-ones

Comment: @basavarajganagi no it's same what i do  here , this not a solution

if i add same methodes in my app/gradle like this : 
   implementation project(':mylib')
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'
it will raise an error for multidex task